# Fill MySQL tables from HTML selection boxes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I use a form for myself to place some values in a `MySQL` database. However, I don't know how to work with selection boxes.

I have eight selection boxes I can check and based on that, I write it to 8 different tables. So if option 1, 3 and 6 are checked I have to write to those tables.

The code below outputs it to the screen but my array looks different every time because I have different selections each time.

```
<?php
$categorie= array_values($_POST['categorie']);

foreach($categorie as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

What is the best way for me to do this? Place each value in a variable and work with if-else statements or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two select boxes in a form:

```
<form method="post" action="/file.php">
  <select name="fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  </select>
  <select name="vegetable">
    <option value="broccoli">Broccoli</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This form posts the values to file.php which could look like this:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $param => $value)
  switch($param) {
    case 'fruit':
      // $value is your fruit
      break;
    case 'vegetable':
      // $value is your vegetable
      break;
  }
```

Comment: I guess the answers are practically the same. Using a switch case in this case is a good solution to keep a clear overview of your code and it's easy to add more 'cases' for new form input elements. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a switch statement inside your for loop. This requires the value to be numeric so $_POST['category'] would have to be an array of numbers. You could then do this:

```
<?php
    $category= array_values($_POST['category']);

    foreach($category as $key => $value){
        switch($value){
            case 1: mysqli_query("Insert to table 1 here"); break;
            case 2: mysqli_query("Insert to table 2 here"); break;
            case 3: mysqli_query("Insert to table 3 here"); break;
            case 4: mysqli_query("Insert to table 4 here"); break;
            case 5: mysqli_query("Insert to table 5 here"); break;
            case 6: mysqli_query("Insert to table 6 here"); break;
            case 7: mysqli_query("Insert to table 7 here"); break;
            case 8: mysqli_query("Insert to table 8 here"); break;
        }
    }
?>
```